# Appending a key value at root node and all its children in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is the JSON Object i am working on :

```
var r={
"id": "A",
"name": "Analysis",
"url": "A.html",
"root": true,
    "children": [

{
    "id": "B",
    "name": "Introduction",
    "url": "B.html",
    "root": true,
    "children": [{
        "id": "C",
        "name": "Creating",
        "url": "c.html#I1"
    }, {
        "id": "D",
        "name": "Running",
        "url": "d.html#I2"
    }]
},

{
    "id": "E",
    "name": "Transient Analysis",
    "url": "E.html",
    "root": true,
        "children": [{
        "id": "F",
        "name": "RC",
        "url": "F.html#T1"
    }, {
        "id": "G",
        "name": "RLC",
        "url": "G.html#T2"
    }]
}

]
}
```

I want this as another key-value

```
path="home.html"
```

and it should be appended not only to the root node but to all its children node.

So it should look like.

```
 var r=  {
"id": "A",
"name": "Analysis",
"url": "A.html",
"path":"home.html",
"root": true,
    "children": [

{
    "id": "B",
    "name": "Introduction",
    "url": "B.html",
    "root": true,
    "path":"home.html",
    "children": [{
        "id": "C",
        "name": "Creating",
        "url": "c.html#I1",
        "path":"home.html"
    }, {
        "id": "D",
        "name": "Running",
        "url": "d.html#I2",
        "path":"home.html"
    }]
},

{
    "id": "E",
    "name": "Transient Analysis",
    "url": "E.html",
    "root": true,
    "path":"home.html",
        "children": [{
        "id": "F",
        "name": "RC",
        "url": "F.html#T1",
        "path":"home.html"
    }, {
        "id": "G",
        "name": "RLC",
        "url": "G.html#T2",
        "path":"home.html"
    } ]
}

]
}
```

so far I've tried is this :

```
r.path={"home.html"}
```

and

```
var to_concatjson = JSON.parse(r);
to_concatjson["path"] = {"home.html"};
```

but both are not working for me.

**Further Modifications in the above question :**

Lets say i am loading my json content from my File 1

File 1 looks like

```
[ 

{
   "id":"a", "name":"a","children":[
          {     "id":"b", "name":"b","children":[    

                                {     "id":"b", "name":"b"},
                                 {     "id":"c", "name":"c"},
                                 {     "id":"d", "name":"d"}
                                 ]
           },

       {     "id":"e", "name":"e","children":[    

                                {     "id":"f", "name":"f"},
                                 {     "id":"g", "name":"g"},
                                 {     "id":"h", "name":"h"}
                                 ]
           },



]
}
]
```

the content of my json file is loaded in result[0]. and when i am calling addPath like :

```
result[0]=addPath(result[0]);
```

it shows me an error that "forEach" will not work as it is not the property of object.

Comment: That's a JavaScript object literal. There's no JSON there.

Comment: @Quentin : i just converted my JSON File content to JavaScript object literal for convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with this code :-

```
function addPath(obj){
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty('path')){
        obj.path = 'home.html';
    }
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty('children')){
        obj.children.forEach(function(obj1){
            obj1 = addPath(obj1);
        });
    }
    return obj;
}

r =  addPath(r);
```

Comment: it only works for the root node. no "path" is added to any of the root children. I checked it twice. whenever i try to get the path value from children it always return  "undefined"

Comment: Its there, how are you accessing children path value?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(r.children[0].children[0].path)); this is giving me home.html

Comment: Thank you !! Its working on browser.you saved my time.

Comment: when i am passing object lets say result[0] having the json content to addPath function then it only works for the root node and then it shows the error that object dose not support the property forEach. what is the reason behind this?

Comment: please have a look of the question again.

Comment: @Rudra pleae check this link http://jsfiddle.net/napst3r/8Ls7wxm7/2/  again. I have checked it with your updated JSON and its working fine for me.

Comment: Its working on browser but when i run it in my environment it gives an error. I think the problem is from my end. Anyways Thanks!! ACCEPTED YOUR ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

I know that my way is not optimum, but it is working:

I append new item through **`.replace(...)`** (without loop)

```
var r  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r).replace(new RegExp("\"url\"", 'g'), '"path": "home.html", "url"'));
console.log(r);
```

```js
var r={
"id": "A",
"name": "Analysis",
"url": "A.html",
"root": true,
    "children": [

{
    "id": "B",
    "name": "Introduction",
    "url": "B.html",
    "root": true,
    "children": [{
        "id": "C",
        "name": "Creating",
        "url": "c.html#I1"
    }, {
        "id": "D",
        "name": "Running",
        "url": "d.html#I2"
    }]
},

{
    "id": "E",
    "name": "Transient Analysis",
    "url": "E.html",
    "root": true,
        "children": [{
        "id": "F",
        "name": "RC",
        "url": "F.html#T1"
    }, {
        "id": "G",
        "name": "RLC",
        "url": "G.html#T2"
    }]
}

]
}
var r  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r).replace(new RegExp("\"url\"", 'g'), '"path": "home.html", "url"'));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Yes its working, but its is depending upon 'url' key. If 'url' isn't present is any of its children then this code will never add 'path' in it.

Comment: yeah, i know. it is not optimum way.